# How array data stored in a session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a challenge in getting back the array i stored in a session.
I stored the array in a array like this

```
$downlines = '2,3,4,5,6,7,8';
$_SESSION['downline'] = $afrisoft->dbarray("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE id IN $downlines")
```

When i print_r the session i get this

```
Array (
      [0] => Array (
                   [username] => mcbel 
                   [email] => firstmail@gmail.com
                   )
      [1] => Array (
                   [username] => bimibola
                   [email] => secondmail@yahoo.com
                   )
      [2] => Array (
                   [username] => shadie
                   [email] => thirdmail@gmail.com
                   )
      [3] => Array (
                   [username] => Hifee
                   [email] => ife@ife.net
                   )
      )
```

What i intend to achieve is to get the data stored in `['usernmae']` and `['email']`, however when i try to `print_r($_SESSION['downline']['username'])` and `print_r($_SESSION['downline']['email'])` it returns no values.

I'll appreciate any help i can get on this.

Comment: if you view the data in your browser you should try to do something like this: "echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION)" it will give you a nice formatted output instead of the single-line mess you get if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array that is returned by your function. you can access the first element of that array by `$_SESSION['downline'][0]['username']`

you can access the full results by traversing through `$_SESSION['downline']` by doing

```
foreach ($_SESSION['downline'] as $item) {
   echo $item['username']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

foreach($_SESSION['downline'] as $userDetails){
    echo $userDetails['username'];
}
```